# How to update Frame Content from View Model, without using the Uri Source, but a constructor

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

Is it possible to bind to this:

```
<Frame Content="{Binding CurrentContent}" />
```

instead of this:

```
<Frame Source="{Binding CurrentContentUri}" />
```

In my view model I would have something like:

```
private ContentControl currentPage;

public ContentControl CurrentContent
{
    get
    {
        return this.currentPage;
    }
    protected set
    {
        this.Set<ContentControl>(ref this.currentPage, value);
    }
}
```

and trigger it as:

```
this.CurrentContent = new ContentControl() { Content = new AccountWidgetPage() };
```

However, two issues:

1. The designer doesn't like at all my XAML

> InvalidOperationException: Page can have only Window or Frame as
>   parent.

2. `new ContentControl()` doesn't seem right to me.

So basically, how do I dynamically update the content binding of the `Frame`, without pointing it to a XAML (I want to use a non-default constructor, because I have DI in place).

Comment: Change the type of the CurrentContent property to object or Page and assign it to an instance of your Page?: public object CurrentContent { get; } = new AccountWidgetPage();

Comment: yes, actually that's it. Please post it as an answer so I can accept it, or alternatively I can delete the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of the CurrentContent property to object or Page and assign it to an instance of your Page, e.g.:

```
public object CurrentContent { get; } = new AccountWidgetPage();
```